# Chrome DevTools Timeline: Frame View appears inconsistent with Records chart

Tags: javascript, css, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to understand the [Chrome DevTools Timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline) tab.

I have recorded some activity in my webpage - here is a screenshot of the output:
[image]

Notice at the top "vertical bars graph" I selected the time frame of one bar, which correlates with one frame. The bar is almost completely green (meaning most of the time was spent on "painting").
The middle graph shows alot of yellow, and if I expand the little arrow next to the wide yellow bar at the bottom I can see it contains some purple as well.

There's the wide "empty green bar" at the bottom of the middle graph that appears to have been ignored in the bottom pie chart. I'm guessing that has to do with the fact that it's a separate thread. Is it true that the bottom pie chart only considers the main thread?

If so then the bottom 2 graphs - the horizontal bars and the pie chart - appear to be consistent.
What I don't understand is why the top graph shows almost all "green", which appears to be inconsistent with the other graphs.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The empty green bar that you see, could mean a few things:

1. As you said, the main thread for Javascript rendering was busy processing something else.
2. The GPU was super busy at the time, and wasn't able to keep up - which can usually be caused by various CSS filters or other visual effects that the page makes use of.

Try enabling the "CPU Activity" feature within the timeline.

As for the empty green bar appearing in the pie chart, I'm not sure if it's supposed to be there.